# How can a continuous Azure WebJob be notified of a new message on a queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-sdk-.net, azure-queues

A continuous webjob is running processing messages off a queue (normal priority). However, it wants to be notified if another queue (high priority) has any messages and to then switch to processing messages off that queue until empty and then revert to the original queue.

How can this be achieved? I don't want to manually check the high priority queue before processing each message as this will cost an IO operation (chargeable). 
As far as I know, webjobs can't directly communicate with each other - so using another webjob with a queue trigger I don't think will work (please tell me if incorrect).

Comment: Why not run two queue-triggered Web Jobs? This would seem to solve the issue with no downside, unless you are trying to *not* deliver messages from the normal priority queue while delivering high priority messages?

Comment: @SimonW Yes, that's right - plus a little more complicated. I didn't want to write the complete scenario background as I thought it would distract from this question but essentially the webjob is taking messages off a queue and is processing them at a throttled rate (throttled by time such as 1 per second set by external API). That's the bottleneck. The only way I could think of accomplishing that simply was with a continuous webjob with a timer. Maybe this architecture is incorrect - I might open another question about this.

Comment: I think the use of Webjobs this way is probably not the right fit. You maybe want to control the rate at which messages are being fed into the incoming pipeline (queue) and control it that way, rather than try and throttle at the output. Danger is if you feed too many messages into your queue and you take too long to process the message then perhaps it's either stale at processing *or* expires on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Ritchie, you should consider the use of Azure Service Bus , then use Priority queues. There is a great post detailing the how to in this [**blog post**](http://markheath.net/post/priority-queues-with-azure-service-bus)
Mark used tow techniques:

> a very simple way to achieve priority queues is to have two (or more) queues. One queue is for high priority messages, and the other for low priority. Whenever you send a message, you pick which queue to send it to. So this technique assumes that the code sending the message knows whether it should be high priority or not, and also knows how many priority queues there are.

**The second technique** was:

> An alternative approach is to make use of Azure Service Bus topics and subscriptions. With this approach, the messages are all sent to the same topic. But a piece of metadata is included with the message that can be used to partition the messages into high and low priorities.